# mongo can not connect to mongodb server

Tags: mongodb

I just installed mongodb on windows 10.

### The server part

```
$ mongod --auth --dbpath ./db/
2017-04-26T15:08:27.905+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=244 port=27017 dbpath=./db 64-bit host=DESKTOP-NK0JQ4S
2017-04-26T15:08:27.906+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2017-04-26T15:08:27.907+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.4
2017-04-26T15:08:27.907+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd
2017-04-26T15:08:27.907+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2017-04-26T15:08:27.908+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-04-26T15:08:27.908+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-04-26T15:08:27.909+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-04-26T15:08:27.909+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2017-04-26T15:08:27.909+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-04-26T15:08:27.909+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-04-26T15:08:27.910+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "./db/" } }
2017-04-26T15:08:27.914+0800 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in ./db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-04-26T15:08:27.915+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3525M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-04-26T15:08:28.795+0800 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory './db/diagnostic.data'
2017-04-26T15:08:28.798+0800 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-04-26T15:08:34.860+0800 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:59658 #1 (1 connection now open)
```

### The connection part

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
```

> This just shows that it is connecting to MongoDB, but can not connect to the MongoDB server.

Comment: Why do you say that "can not connect to the MongoDB server"? Don't you see the shell prompt? Or is it that you cannot perform any operations in there? If so, please note that you are using `--auth`, so yo will need a user to validate.
Have you checked the log file for clues? Best,
Javier

Comment: It looks like it _is_ connected, both from the client log and the server log.

Comment: According to the log your connection is open and waiting for information. Perhaps you did not set up any code to send information to a collection? Or you did not create a collection yet? The log says you are good to go.